# Как добавить кнопку КУПИТЬ?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имею сайт WordPress с WooCommerce.
Хочу сделать в карточке товара кнопку купить прилепленную снизу страницы.
Подумал что можно сделать это хуком, вывести дубль кнопки и через css прилепить КНОПКУ внизу .
Использую это

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_add_to_cart', 20);
```

но дубль не появляется,

а это выводит кнопку в СПИСКЕ ТОВАРОВ,  а нужно в карточке товара

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'lets_add_cart_button' );
function lets_add_cart_button() {
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
}
```

может кто подскажет ХУК как вывести ДУБЛЬ кнопки КУПИТЬ? (вместе с ценой можно) (ТОЛЬКО В КАРТОЧКЕ ТОВАРА)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

первый вариант вы можете использовать action для перемещения кнопки на странице товара. например вот

отключить отображения кнопки

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

вывести кнопку в новом месте (после описания)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

вы можете ознакомится со всеми местами куда можно добавить свой блок на странице товара по той ссылке
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

второй вариант вы можете использовать шорткод woocommerce [add_to_cart id="99"] где id это id товара. например вот так.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_add_to_cart_button' );

function show_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    echo do_shortcode( '[add_to_cart id="' . $product->get_id() . '"]' );
}
```

подробнее о шорткодах woocommerce можно прочитать здесь https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: Все зависит от того как вы это сделали, можно обернуть шорткод в свой тег, можно добавить класс к шаблону кнопки, можно обойтись без всего это используя css. Если ответ помог отметьте его как решание

Comment: Я добавил в функици темы ------------------------add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 3 );----------- но для упрщения css, хотелось бы обернуть в свой стиль это все дело